# How can i import data with uneven row lengths

Tags: arrays, matlab

I have a *.txt* file I wish to import into matlab (thinking using importdata), however I have some issues telling matlab the format, as well as how much of the data to take in.

The file is generated from the program *"TurbSim"*.

**The format is:**

- 12 rows of headers
- 1 line with 2 numerical values, spacing delimiter is done with an
  empty space.
- 35 lines each with 35 numerical values, spacing delimiter is done
  with an  empty space.
- 1 empty line of space

The format, after the headers, repeat and I have a very large file, I've not been able to find a way in a script to load up the file correctly where I have control over how large a portion i wish to take out. Which I may need as the file is ~860MB.

Example txt of my issue. **fixed**
https://drive.google.com/open?id=1FwmrCiz6TaWXYwXYX_v0BwQD-jjbdsE4

Comment: Link to example says "File not Found".

Comment: That is odd, I'll reupload, very sorry for the slow response time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about this?

```
clear;

NUM_HEADERLINES = 12;
DELIM_VALUES = ' ';

fid = fopen('TurbSim.txt');
% skip header
for n = 1:NUM_HEADERLINES, fgets(fid);end

while ~feof(fid)
    % read line
    [line,nl] = fgets(fid);
    % remove newline char
    line = line(1:end-length(nl)); 
    % explode using delimiter
    values = strsplit(line,DELIM_VALUES);
    % in case of leading blanks: skip first empty one
    if isempty(values{1}), values = values(2:end);end
    % skip blank lines
    if isempty(values), continue;end
    % convert to double
    values = str2double(values);
    % now process/save/whatever...
    ...
    fprintf('Read %d values\n',length(values)); % in your example: 2 or 40
%     disp(values);
end

fclose(fid);
```

Btw: your examples has 40 lines with 40 values each, not 35 with 35 each.

Comment: Ah I had forgotten I recently changed my size to a 40x40 grid. Sorry about that, but this seems like it will work :) ! Thank you very very much!